# Where to put JUnit test in Android project

Tags: android, testing, junit, android-testing

To run my JUnit tests on my Android application, do I have to create a different project or I can include them in my project? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

This link from android developers provides full explanations:
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html

Tests should be included in the same project nearby `src` folder

Answer (score 0):

**JUnit Test** in **Android** is same as it was in ***Java***.
You can also create **Android Test Project**
for more information please visit: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html
and
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_eclipse.html